# Casting down the hierarchy and equals in java

Tags: java, casting

I have the following code

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof ColorPoint))
        return false;
    return super.equals(o) && ((ColorPoint) o).color == color;
}
```

And i have the following

```
Point p = new Point(1, 2);
ColorPoint cp = new ColorPoint(1, 2, Color.RED);
```

`ColorPoint` inherits `Point`. The problem is when I do `p.equals(cp)` why it return `true`? I mean in the last return it call `super.equal` but at that cast what happens? What it returns at that cast with `ColorPoint`

```
@Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
if (!(o instanceof Point))
return false;
Point p = (Point)o;
return p.x == x && p.y == y;
}
```

This is the equal from Point class

Comment: Does `ColorPoint` extend class `Point`? Is that `equals` method in class `Point` or class `ColorPoint`? What does the `equals` method in the superclass look like?

Comment: Since `cp` _is a_ `Point` `p.equals(cp)` will return true. If you don't want that then use `o.getClass() == Point.class` (or `o.getClass() == getClass()`) (and of course check for `o == null` first).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `equals` method of `Point`, not the one of `ColorPoint`.

Change to `cp.equals(p)` and you'll get `false`.

Note that you should not implement `equals` in a way that could make it asymmetrically. Always check, if the classes match, if you want to extend a class:

```
// in Point class
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == null || getClass() != other.getClass()) {
         return false;
    }
    Point p = (Point) other;
    return p.x == x && p.y == y;
}
```

Comment: yes now i see. i was not paying atention to that. my bad

Comment: Mark any answer as a correct answer and then upvote them as you will already have 15 reputation. That's what we do on [so].

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers your implementation of `equals()` violates the contract as defined in the JavaDocs:

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null object references:
>
> - ...
> - It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
>
>   ...

That means you *should not* check for `o instanceof Point` but for `o.getClass() == getClass()`. With your implementation you get a different result when calling `p.equals(cp)` and `cp.equals(p)` and thus you violate that contract. This could cause subtle bugs since most collections rely on that contract.

Comment: i know. it is from a book that debate this thing but in a moment when i didn't pay enough attention(now i know what i was mistaken) i was wondering what happens in return with that cast but a guy asked me to put the Point equal and then i remembered that it calls equal from Point\

Answer (score 0):

Your `equals` method is implemented for `ColorPoint`. You call `equals` on Point. It will only check two coordinates - not a color.

You will get `false` if you call `cp.equals(p);`

Answer (score 0):

Class hierarchies and `equals()` don't go well together.

If you implement `equals()` in superclass using `instanceof` (so that subclasses can be equal to superclasses), you break the requirement for `equals()` to by symmetric:

```
p.equals(cp) // true
cp.equals(p) // false
```

If you implement it using `getClass().equals(other.getClass())`, you'll get correct contract, but prevent any subclass instances from ever being equal to your instance - this may be a problem e.g. when using an ORM like Hibernate that creates proxy classes for your classes.

The only situation where `equals()` seems to work well across multiple classes is when you have an interface and define the *contract* of `equals()` in terms of that interface's methods, then write all the implementations so that they honor the contract and only use the info exposed by the interface. This can be seen for example in `java.util.List` and its common implementations.